# How can I send a ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE Broadcast from Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-broadcast, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

In my "java" application, I have this code in my getDataFromServer() function (Which is called by my WorkManager every 2 hours and my MainActivity Onrefresh() ) in order to update my homescreen widget with fresh data:

```
AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(
        new ComponentName(context,MyWidgetProvider.class));
Intent updateIntent = new Intent();
updateIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
updateIntent.putExtra(MyWidgetProvider.WIDGET_ID_KEY, ids);
context.sendBroadcast(updateIntent);
```

This will make my ,MyAppWidgetProvider to "wake up", to read the fresh data from a file and update.

Now, I have moved my logic to Flutter, and I have no idea how to call this code from my Dart code.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference package https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget

In native part https://github.com/ABausG/home_widget/blob/3de5ff703e9f8f7700036a23e609e0627976f904/android/src/main/kotlin/es/antonborri/home_widget/HomeWidgetPlugin.kt#L61

```
"updateWidget" -> {
                val className = call.argument<String>("android") ?: call.argument<String>("name")
                try {
                    val javaClass = Class.forName("${context.getPackageName()}.${className}")
                    val intent = Intent(context, javaClass)
                    intent.action = AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE
                    val ids: IntArray = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context.applicationContext).getAppWidgetIds(ComponentName(context, javaClass))
                    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids)
                    context.sendBroadcast(intent)
                } catch (classException: ClassNotFoundException) {
                    result.error("-3", "No Widget found with Name $className. Argument 'name' must be the same as your AppWidgetProvider you wish to update", classException)
                }
            }
```

In Dart part for `Background Update`
https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget#background-update
As the methods of `HomeWidget` are static it is possible to use `HomeWidget` in the background to update the Widget even when the App is in the background.
The example App is using the `flutter_workmanager` plugin to achieve this

https://github.com/ABausG/home_widget/blob/3de5ff703e9f8f7700036a23e609e0627976f904/example/lib/main.dart#L10

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((taskName, inputData) {
    debugPrint('Native called background task: $taskName');

    final now = DateTime.now();
    return Future.wait<bool>([
      HomeWidget.saveWidgetData('title', 'Updated from Background'),
      HomeWidget.saveWidgetData('message',
          '${now.year}-${now.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${now.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')} ${now.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${now.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${now.second.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}'),
      HomeWidget.updateWidget(
          name: 'HomeWidgetExampleProvider', iOSName: 'HomeWidgetExample'),
    ]).then((value) {
      return !value.contains(false);
    });
  });
}

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Workmanager.initialize(callbackDispatcher, isInDebugMode: kDebugMode);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```